# Rename object keys of return object

Tags: javascript, typescript

### Szenario

A method *matter* returns an object, like `return {content, data}`

### Conflict

The second call of the method (a method from a node module) overwrites previous vars set from return.

```js
import matter from 'gray-matter'

const test = () => {
...
   const { content, data } = matter(source1)
   const { content, data } = matter(source2) // this overwrites previous content, data vars
...
}
```

## Goal / Question

Setting the return values in different named vars, like:

```
const { content2, data2 } = matter(source2) // like so it leads to an compiling error property content2 does not exists on type [...]
```

**So, how can be the return values assigned to different named vars as they are named in the type?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use different variable names:

```
const { content, data } = matter(source1)
const { content: content2, data: data2 } = matter(source2)
```

Or don't destructure at all:

```
const result1 = matter(source1)
const result2 = matter(source2)
```

Or use an array of objects:

```
const results = [source1, source2].map(matter);
```